# how to select the latest date in xdocument in c#

Tags: c#, xml

I am newbie in xml file c#. I am trying to remove duplicates from an XML and keep only newest by date by select process through combobox selected item:

```
*The XML structure is:

    <Trace>
       <Log>
       <Process>NPP</Process>
       <LineNo>14</LineNo>
       <Date>12/3/2019 5:47:53 PM</Date>
       <Result>Passed</Result>
       </Log>
       <Log>
       <Process>WET</Process>
       <LineNo>14</LineNo>
       <Date>12/3/2019 5:50:54 PM</Date>
       <Result>Passed</Result>
       </Log>
       <Log>
       <Process>CPL</Process>
       <LineNo>14</LineNo>
       <Date>19/3/2019 5:14:07 AM</Date>
       <Result>Re-input</Result>
       </Log>
       <Log>
       <Process>CPL</Process>
       <LineNo>14</LineNo>
       <Date>19/3/2019 5:17:40 AM</Date>
       <Result>Re-input</Result>
       </Log>
       <Log>
       <Process>CPL</Process>
       <LineNo>14</LineNo>
       <Date>19/3/2019 6:27:43 AM</Date>
       <Result>Re-input</Result>
       </Log>
   </Trace>
```

The data still display the 3 result if i select process 'CPL'. What i have tried.
    *The code is:

```
    var xdoc1 = XDocument.Load(@"D:\DataDirectory\DataDirectory145\Product\149329.xml");

    var NewDoc1 = new XDocument(new XElement("Trace",from anEntry in xdoc1.Element("Trace").Elements("Log")
                                    where anEntry.Element("Process").Value.Contains(cmbProcess.SelectedItem.ToString())
                                    orderby anEntry.Element("Date").Value.ToString().First()
                                    select anEntry)
                                    );

        var myList = (from bEntry in NewDoc.Descendants("SerialNo")
                      from bEntry1 in NewDoc1.Descendants("Log")
                      select new
                      {
                          Product_Serial_No = Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(bEntry.Element("Product").Value),
                          PWB_Serial_No = Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(bEntry.Element("PWB").Value),
                          Process = bEntry1.Element("Process").Value,
                          Line_No = bEntry1.Element("LineNo").Value,
                          Date = bEntry1.Element("Date").Value,
                          Result = bEntry1.Element("Result").Value
                      }
                     ).ToList();
```

*I expect the output will display the latest date like this:

### | Product  | PWB      | Process | Line No | Date                 | Result   |

| 149329.. | 149329.. | CPL     |    14   | 19/3/2019 6:27:43 AM | Re-input |

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could order (by descending) the Log Decendants by the value of Element Date and select the First Item.

For Example

```
   var result = xDoc.Descendants("Log")
                    .OrderByDescending(x=> DateTime.Parse(x.Element("Date").Value))
                    .Select(x=> 
                        new
                        {
                            Process = (string)x.Element("Process").Value,
                            Line = (string)x.Element("LineNo").Value,
                            Date = DateTime.Parse(x.Element("Date").Value),
                            Result = (string)x.Element("Result").Value
                        })
                    .First();
```

Sample Output

[image]

Comment: Thank you very much! Exactly what I was looking for.